# Not able to find Kindle AVD option in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, kindle-fire

I followed the guidelines from following URL: https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/setup.html

but I cannot find the kindle AVD or Kindle Devices in the list.

I only get the option of Kindle Fire USB Driver which is for Windows.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(A bit late) but the Kindle Emulators are no longer supported. 
http://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14638&#14638